# Cosa significa "impianto" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Questa frase, tratta dal romanzo *Artemisia* di Anna Banti, descrive il pensiero che ha la pittrice prima di cominciare a lavorare su un ritratto della regina Enrichetta di Francia, sposa del re Carlo I d'Inghilterra:

> Come, d'altronde, meditare **l'impianto** e studiare il soggetto davanti a una regina in posa?

Non capisco il significato di "impianto" in questo testo. Ho cercato questo vocabolo in alcuni dizionari, ma tutte le accezioni che ho trovato si riferiscono a macchine oppure sono termini medici. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "impianto" nel brano precedente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il termine ***[impianto](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/I/impianto.php)*** può essere usato anche in riferimento alla struttura di un pensiero o di un libro ad esempio:

> - Struttura, organizzazione, impostazione: *un ragionamento di impianto razionalistico*.

La pittrice sta pensando  a come impostare il dipinto (i soggetti, le pose, i colori etc.) trattandosi di un soggetto così importante.

(Hoepli)